# XML parser handles string value 1 as boolean

Tags: xml

From our webapplication X we export a XML-file containing data we want to import in application Y.

When each item in the exported XML-file has value "1" for  or  application Y handles this like it's a boolean and returns ".T.". 
Application Y does not offer a way to force it to import the value as a string.

Do we need to add something to the XML-file to always let application Y interpreter the value as a string? Or is there another way to fix our problem?

An example of our exportfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>
    <item>
        <dj_code><![CDATA[FAC]]></dj_code>
        <page_nr>1</page_nr>
        <hdr_desc><![CDATA[test testcase 20120001]]></hdr_desc>
        <date><![CDATA[2012-03-30]]></date>
        <sub_nr>8095</sub_nr>
        <acct_nr>8200</acct_nr>
        <inv_nr>20120001</inv_nr>
        <desc><![CDATA[vierkantemeters]]></desc>
        <vat_code><![CDATA[T]]></vat_code>
        <period>03</period>
        <amount>1500.00</amount>
    </item>

    <item>
        <dj_code><![CDATA[FAC]]></dj_code>
        <page_nr>1</page_nr>
        <hdr_desc><![CDATA[test testcase 20120001]]></hdr_desc>
        <date><![CDATA[2012-03-30]]></date>
        <sub_nr>8095</sub_nr>
        <acct_nr>8200</acct_nr>
        <inv_nr>20120001</inv_nr>
        <desc><![CDATA[meters lat]]></desc>
        <vat_code><![CDATA[T]]></vat_code>
        <period>03</period>
        <amount>50.00</amount>
    </item>

    <item>
        <dj_code><![CDATA[FAC]]></dj_code>
        <page_nr>1</page_nr>
        <hdr_desc><![CDATA[test testcase 20120001]]></hdr_desc>
        <date><![CDATA[2012-03-30]]></date>
        <sub_nr>8095</sub_nr>
        <acct_nr>8200</acct_nr>
        <inv_nr>20120001</inv_nr>
        <desc><![CDATA[tester]]></desc>
        <vat_code><![CDATA[T]]></vat_code>
        <period>03</period>
        <amount>500.00</amount>
    </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0):

What language/library are you using to import the xml?

You can add a schema or dtd to your exported xml and whatever is parsing it should then respect the types of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If application Y is interpreting "1" as true, and you don't want this to happen, then you need to understand application Y in order to solve the problem, and we need to understand application Y in order to help you. Since we know nothing at all about application Y, other than it's odd interpretation of "1", helping you is very difficult.

Comment: You're right. There is no Api for application Y. Will contact the manufacturer for more information on the parser etc.